# Decrease per thread memory in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, memory

I have a C++ application which creates huge number of threads. With ulimit -v unlimited, application crashes with segfault after creating 1080 threads. Crash happens when I'm trying to access memory allocated with "new". "new" returns non-null pointer, but access to it issues segfault.
With ulimit -v 500000, application doesn't crash, but limits maximum number of threads (pthread_create fails - much better behaviour).
According to top, application crashes (ulimit -v unlimited) when total memory reaches size of physical RAM.
I need to have ~1500 threads (I know the drawbacks...)
Threads are very small, according to valgrind, each thread uses ~16kb of stack, so I don't know why so much memory is occupied by application.
What can I change/check to decrease per-thread memory ? ulimit -s 1024 doesn't help.

Comment: You can use `valgrind` with `massif` tool to inspect what memory is used for. Also having 1080 threads seems rather pointless.

Comment: I haven't used valgrind for a while, but be aware that the amount of memory _used_ by a stack is not necessarily the same thing as the amount of memory that is _reserved_ for the stack.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with `new` returning a non-null pointer but crashing when accessing that memory is Linux memory overcommit "feature". [`man malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html):

> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy. This means that when `malloc()` returns non-NULL there is no guarantee that the memory really is available. In case it turns out that the system is out of memory, one or more processes will be killed by the OOM killer. For more information, see the description of `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and `/proc/sys/vm/oom_adj` in `proc(5)`, and the Linux kernel source file `Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting`.

---

[`man pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> On Linux/x86-32, the default stack size for a new thread is 2 megabytes. Under the NPTL threading implementation, if the `RLIMIT_STACK` soft resource limit at the time the program started has any value other than "unlimited", then it determines the default stack size of new threads. Using `pthread_attr_setstacksize(3)`, the stack size attribute can be explicitly set in the attr argument used to create a thread, in order to obtain a stack size other than the default.